# Oracle SQL Join query results

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following two tables

```
Table 1: SOURCE_SYSTEM 
ID  CODE    Source ID   Source Name
123 111 Monster Dice.com 
456 111 Dice    ABC COMPANY
456 888 Ticv    A2 systems
4566    999 MOnster hgtt solutions
789 222 Monster ABC COMPANY
985 222 Dice    Dice.com 

Table 2: TARGET_SYSTEM 
RECORDID    AI CL ID    Source Name Op Code
123 111 Dice.com    Secondary
456 111 ABC COMPANY Primary
789 222 ABC COMPANY Secondary
985 222 Dice.com    Primary
```

We have a process which runs gets the data from source table and loads into target table. But in here the process has a rule saying the primary row in Target should has the Source Name from Source table where Source ID = ‘Monster’.
Here the following entry in Target is correct

```
RECORDID    AI CL ID    Source Name Op Code
123 111 Dice.com    Secondary
456 111 ABC COMPANY Primary
```

But the following is wrong, has Primary Source name is Dice.com which should be ABC COMPANY.

```
RECORDID    AI CL ID    Source Name Op Code
789 222 ABC COMPANY Secondary
985 222 Dice.com    Primary
```

So I need a query which can identify all the rows in Target which the same issue.

Comment: Your question is not clear to me and I'm afraid other readers might think the same way. Please try to explain better what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are the two rows for AI_CL_ID = 111 correct? They are wrong according to your specification, because recorded = 123 corresponds to 'Monster' but it has 'Secondary' in your `target_system` table.

To find all the rows in the `target_system` table with the wrong `op_code` you can use the following query. Assumptions: The pair (id, code) is unique `target_system`; there are no NULLs in any column; the `source_name` in `target_system` is always correct (it matches the `source_name` in `source_system` when matched by `id` and `code`); the marker `'Primary'` is special, but there may be other markers besides `'Secondary'`.

The solution does not include the rows from "with" to the closing " ) " after the definition of `target_system`; the WITH clause is used to generate test data within the query itself, but in real life you should simply start with `select t.id, ...` and hit your base tables or views.

```
with
     source_system ( id, code, source_id, source_name) as (
       select  123, 111, 'Monster', 'Dice.com'       from dual union all 
       select  456, 111, 'Dice'   , 'ABC COMPANY'    from dual union all 
       select  456, 888, 'Ticv'   , 'A2 systems'     from dual union all 
       select 4566, 999, 'MOnster', 'hgtt solutions' from dual union all 
       select  789, 222, 'Monster', 'ABC COMPANY'    from dual union all 
       select  985, 222, 'Dice'   , 'Dice.com'       from dual
     ),
     target_system ( recordid, ai_cl_id, source_name, op_code ) AS (
       select 123, 111, 'Dice.com'   , 'Secondary' from dual union all
       select 456, 111, 'ABC COMPANY', 'Primary'   from dual union all
       select 789, 222, 'ABC COMPANY', 'Secondary' from dual union all
       select 985, 222, 'Dice.com'   , 'Primary'   from dual
     )
select t.recordid, t.ai_cl_id, t.source_name, t.op_code
from   target_system t inner join source_system s
                       on t.recordid = s.id and t.ai_cl_id = s.code
where  ( s.source_id  = 'Monster' and t.op_code != 'Primary' )
       or
       ( s.source_id != 'Monster' and t.op_code  = 'Primary' )
order by ai_cl_id, recordid
;
```

**Output** (with your inputs; the output is different from that in your post since what you have in your post is wrong, as I explained).

```
  RECORDID   AI_CL_ID SOURCE_NAME OP_CODE 
---------- ---------- ----------- ---------
       123        111 Dice.com    Secondary
       456        111 ABC COMPANY Primary  
       789        222 ABC COMPANY Secondary
       985        222 Dice.com    Primary
```